# React Native native-base's advantages?

Tags: react-native, native-base

I'm now studying framework react native native-base.

While reading document, I think it is little bit different with original code.

For example, `<View>` is replace to `<Container>`

Also many codes replace to native-base's style code like this.

[image]

So I'm wondering, are there a lot of people coding in native-base syntax?

Does native-base have any performance problem?

(I know that there are lots of good features, But I'm not talking about that. Just performance, and syntax...)

Comment: There are many apps in the PlayStore and Appstore that use NativeBase. These apps are having the same performance that any react native app have. You can also check NativeBase [issues](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues) for getting an overview on performance.

Answer (score 1):

- NativeBase framework are exposing exactly the same UX as natively written applications because NativeBase uses the React Native platform's **default rendering and layout engine**.
- NativeBase allows to have a **common codebase** for all their application code.
- NativeBase is targeted specially on the look and feel, and UI interplay of your app. **NativeBase without a doubt fits** in well with mobile applications (i.e. use of Container, Header, Footer etc) which cut downs one huge part of your app The Front end.